# Replace multiple files recursively

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, find, cp

I have a file structure like this:

```
experiment/
├── foo.txt
├── source-foo.txt
└── subdir
    └── foo.txt
```

I want to take the file `source-foo.txt` and replace the other foos with it. Just like doing `cp source-foo.txt foo.txt` and `cp source-foo.txt subdir/foo.txt` both at once. I was thinking I could use `find` for this purpose, something like:

```
cp source-foo.txt $(find . -iname foo.txt)
```

But thet returns an error:

```
cp: target „foo.txt“ is not a directory
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: Please take a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding, I got stuck in work. I'll try the solution tonight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU find:

```
cd experiment
find . -name "foo.txt" -exec echo cp -v source-foo.txt {} \;
```

If everything looks okay, remove `echo`.

Output with `echo`:

```
cp -v source-foo.txt ./foo.txt
cp -v source-foo.txt ./subdir/foo.txt
```

Output without `echo`:

```
`source-foo.txt' -> `./foo.txt'
`source-foo.txt' -> `./subdir/foo.txt'
```